# Issues with Spring Batch

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

Hi I have been working in Spring batch recently and need some help.

1) I want to run my Job using multiple threads, hence I have used TaskExecutor as below,

```
            @Bean
            public TaskExecutor taskExecutor() {
                SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor taskExecutor = new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor();
                taskExecutor.setConcurrencyLimit(4);
                return taskExecutor;
            }

    @Bean
        public Step myStep() {
            return stepBuilderFactory.get("myStep")
                    .<MyEntity,AnotherEntity> chunk(1)
                    .reader(reader())
                    .processor(processor())
                    .writer(writer())
                    .taskExecutor(taskExecutor())
                    .throttleLimit(4)
                     .build();
        }
```

but, while executing in can see below line in console.

> o.s.b.c.l.support.SimpleJobLauncher      : No TaskExecutor has been set, defaulting to synchronous executor.

What does this mean? However, while debugging I can see four SimpleAsyncExecutor threads running. Can someone shed some light on this?

2) I don't want to run my Batch application with the metadata tables that spring batch creates. I have tried adding `spring.batch.initialize-schema=never`. But it didn't work. I also saw some way to do this by using `ResourcelessTransactionManager`, `MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean`. But I have to make some database transactions for my job. So will it be alright if I use this?
Also I was able to do this by extending `DefaultBatchConfigurer` and overriding:

```
@Override
    public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
        // override to do not set datasource even if a datasource exist.
        // initialize will use a Map based JobRepository (instead of database)
    }
```

Please guide me further. Thanks.

Update:

My full configuration class here.

```
@EnableBatchProcessing
@EnableScheduling
@Configuration
public class MyBatchConfiguration{

    @Autowired
    public JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    public StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    public DataSource dataSource;


    /* @Override
        public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
            // override to do not set datasource even if a datasource exist.
            // initialize will use a Map based JobRepository (instead of database)
        }*/
    @Bean
    public Step myStep() {

        return stepBuilderFactory.get("myStep")
                .<MyEntity,AnotherEntity> chunk(1)
                .reader(reader())
                .processor(processor())
                .writer(writer())
                .taskExecutor(executor())
                .throttleLimit(4)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Job myJob() {

        return jobBuilderFactory.get("myJob")
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .listener(listener())
                .flow(myStep())
                .end()
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public MyJobListener myJobListener()
    {
        return new MyJobListener();
    }
    @Bean
    public ItemReader<MyEntity> reader()
    {

        return new MyReader();
    }

    @Bean
    public ItemWriter<? super AnotherEntity> writer()
    {
        return new MyWriter();
    }

    @Bean
    public ItemProcessor<MyEntity,AnotherEntity> processor()
    {
        return new MyProcessor();
    }

    @Bean
    public TaskExecutor taskExecutor() {
        SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor taskExecutor = new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor();
        taskExecutor.setConcurrencyLimit(4);
        return taskExecutor;
    }}
```

Comment: 1: sounds like your `taskExecutor`is not picked up by `component-scan`/auto-configuration... 2. also mysterious: as if your `spring.batch.initialize-schema=never` is not piked up!

Comment: May you post your full configuration class?

Comment: @MạnhQuyếtNguyễn I have posted my configuration class

Comment: Try to add `@Primary` above `@Bean` of `taskExecutor()`

Comment: I tried adding `@Primary`. Unfortunately, I still get the same INFO.

Comment: Whats your Spring boot and Batch version?

Comment: @jusermar10 2.0.1.RELEASE is my springboot version that I have used in my pom.xml . However, i have not mentioned any spring-batch version explicitly.

Answer (score 10):

In the future, please break this up into two independent questions.  That being said, let me shed some light on both questions.

**SimpleJobLauncher : No TaskExecutor has been set, defaulting to synchronous executor.**

Your configuration is configuring `myStep` to use your `TaskExecutor`.  What that does is it causes Spring Batch to execute each chunk in it's own thread (based on the parameters of the `TaskExecutor`).  The log message you are seeing has nothing to do with that behavior.  It has to do with *launching* your job.  By default, the `SimpleJobLauncher` will launch the job on the same thread it is running on, thereby blocking that thread.  You *can* inject a `TaskExecutor` into the `SimpleJobLauncher` which will cause the job to be executed on a different thread from the `JobLauncher` itself.  These are two separate uses of multiple threads by the framework.

**I don't want to run my Batch application with the metadata tables that spring batch creates**

The short answer here is to just use an in memory database like HSQLDB or H2 for your metadata tables.  This provides a production grade data store (so that concurrency is handled correctly) without actually persisting the data.  If you use the `ResourcelessTransactionManager`, you are effectively turning transactions off (a bad idea if you're using a database in any capacity) because that `TransactionManager` doesn't actually do anything (it's a no-op implementation).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you please explain a bit more of those two ways of multi threading feature that you have mentioned? Ideally, Which should be chosen when?